# Approaching in Solving Heat Equation given Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

Given the heat equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ that satisfy boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(\frac{\pi}{2} ,t)$, find the solution that satisfies the initial condition that $u(x, 0) = \pi sin(3x) - 5sin(42x)$.

Having a little bit of an issue going about this. The initial condition does not satisfy the boundary conditions (plugging in $x=\frac {\pi}{2}$).

Any idea if there's an error in the wording of the question (copied verbatim), or how I would go about solving this?

Comment: Have you learned about Fourier series solutions?

Comment: As I recall the initial data isn't required to meet the boundary conditions as it's a temperature profile that's immediately introduced in the rod at $t=0$, the solution then evolves from the profile with additional requirements that the ends are then maintained at the same temperature

Comment: Ah, alright. That makes sense. I'll just go in an solve as usual, thanks everyone!